# Why the String input variable won't be saved using return?

Tags: java, string, variables, methods, return

The method won't take the variable that I assigned in return.

```
public static String agregarMain() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingresar nombre del software/topico");
            String mainSeleccion = in.nextLine();
        if (mainSeleccion == "") {
            System.out.println("Invalid Selection, please try again");
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        return mainSeleccion;
        }
    }
```

I'm expecting to save the input response in mainSeleccion variable.

Comment: you compare string with equals method https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object) and your method need a return statement after the for loop

Comment: Declare the variable before the if block

Comment: The central problem here is that not all paths lead to a return statement. Incidentally, yes, the string compare is _also_ wrong. Point is, reopen - that's not the pertinent problem here. Admittedly, OP, you really should include the compiler error message in your SO questions.

Comment: close -> missing debugging information, like, well, what the actual error is...

Answer (score 2):

*All* paths through the code *must* lead to a `return` statement. Some analysis of this code indicates that it should always do so, but this requires knowing that `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` will loop at least once.

The compiler isn't going to go that far. Hence, this won't compile. Just reorder a few things and it will. Separately, you *also* have a second issue - `==` checks reference identity, it doesn't do value comparison. Unless the left and right hand side are primitives (i.e. *not* references, and thus 'reference identity' wouldnt apply in the first place). You use equals instead, or in this case, more idiomatic, `.isEmpty()`. Fixing both issues:

```java
public static String agregarMain() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String mainSeleccion = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingresar nombre del software/topico");
        mainSeleccion = in.nextLine();
        if (mainSeleccion.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Selection, please try again");
            i--;
        }
    }
    return mainSeleccion;
}
```

NB: When asking question on stack overflow, include all pertinent errors. You didnt which led to some confusion in the comments and got your question closed.